# how to use button action in UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift

I want to call this method on tap function :

```
@IBAction func Likes(sender: UIButton!) {
    if let QuotesDetail = self.Array_Quote.object(at: sender.tag) as? NSDictionary {
        if let quote_id  = QuotesDetail.object(forKey: "quote_id") {
            if (sender.isSelected) {
                self.api_addQuoteToFavourite(qt_id: "\(quote_id)", indexP: intmax_t(sender.tag))
                sender.isSelected = false
            }
            else {
                self.api_addQuoteToFavourite(qt_id: "\(quote_id)", indexP: intmax_t(sender.tag))
                sender.isSelected = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my tap function :

```
@objc func handleTap(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
        if let QuotesDetail = self.Array_Quote.object(at: (label.tag)) as? NSDictionary {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what problem you are facing in implementation of it?

Comment: Do a google search for `UITapGestureRecognizer swift` ... you'll find plenty of tutorials and examples. If you then have trouble implementing it, come back and ask specific questions. Please see [ask]

Comment: _Swift Tips:_ to avoid confusion, variables and function names should be `lowerCamelCase`, not `UpperCamelCase`. Don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift - use native `Dictionary` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass `UIButton` which is having `tag`.

```
let btn = UIButton()
btn.tag = 0//you can set whatever you want.
self.Like(sender:btn)
```

you have to handle `sender.isSelected = false` as you are passing new object. Actually it should be same button which you have bind to `Like` method.

If you have same tag of button and label then get your button using `viewWithTag` and pass that button.

```
if let btn = self.view.viewWithTag(label.tag) as? UIButton {
        self.Like(sender:btn)
    }
```

`Like` shoulb be like as it is a function.

Comment: @Prasann enjoy :)

Comment: hello sir i m just fresher can you suggest me some tutorials or anything else for improving my swift ? thanks